# multiple values from different spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been following the tutorials of [Learn Google Spreadsheets](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8p19gUXJYTsUPEpusHgteQ) and are stuck with the following.

In my html file i have got a `select/dropdown` menu that gets the values from a spreadsheet. Thats working fine-) .However, i would like to
add another dropdown that gets his values from another spreadsheet.  I'm trying to do that but keep getting the same values as from the other dropdown.

I already have a function called `loadForm()` and it triggers the values from a given spreadsheet. I have made a second dropdown and a new function to trigger values from another spreadsheet or trigger values from a different sheet. If I set this up, the values from both dropdowns are the same.

this is a piece of my gs code. loadform is the first dropdown:

```
function loadForm() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws =ss.getSheetByName("Options");
var list=ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A2").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
var htmlListArray = list.map(function(r) {return '<option>' + r[0]  +'   
</option>' ;}).
join('');    
return render("page",{list: htmlListArray});
}

function loadAnalyse() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws =ss.getSheetByName("Options2");
var list =  ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A2").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
 var htmlListArray = list.map(function(r) {return '<option>' + r[0]  +   
 '</option>' ; }).
 join('');    
      return render("analyse",{list: htmlListArray});
}
```

Update: This is what I've got so far. The thing what I want to accomplish is to create `multiple dropdowns selections` in the `index.html` file that are getting their values from different sheets. Someone that has a clue for me-)

```
function doGet(e){  
//views
Route.path("form",loadForm); 
Route.path("table",loadTable); 
Route.path("analyse",loadAnalyse);

loadForm = e.parameter 
loadTable = e.parameter.v
loadAnalyse = e.parameter.a   

if(Route[e.parameters.v]) {
  return Route[e.parameters.v]();
} else{
return render ("home");
}

switch(e.parameters.v) {
case v:
return Route[e.parameters.v]();
break;
case a:
return Route[e.parameters.a]();
break;
default:
return render ("Page");
}
```

Comment: i renamed the arays and the dropdown in the html files to list1, but without any succes-(

Comment: Please provide your HTML code

Answer (score 0):

> I can give you only general information without seeing your HTML file

What I can tell you so far, is that

- to create a html output, you need to implement the   `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');` method.[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) you can find more information.
- To create an HTML output in conjunction with your Apps Script, you need to publish your script as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).
- To call an Apps Script function (e.g. function loadForm()) within your script in the HTML file - so you can access its return value - you need to call it with [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).
- I cannot see how you insert `htmlListArray` into your dropdown menu, but to avoid error sources, please give different names to spreadsheets, sheets, lists and arrays, e.g. `ss1`, `ws1`, `list1`, `htmlListArray1`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I did placed the html code but is not posted. With the help of "ziganotschka" and soemeone els it worked out afterall.

```
 html
 <!--dropdown-->
      <div class="input-field col s6">
         <select id ="app" required>

           ><?!=list; ?>

    </select>
    <label></label>
  </div>

  <div class ="row">


 <!--dropdown-->
      <div class="input-field col s6">
         <select id ="app1" required>

           ><?!=list1; ?>      <!-- Changed this to list1 instead of list--
code here`
```

============================================================================

```
code gs:
```

add a list that is called by example list1 theat has to be placed within the array:

```
    function loadAnalyse() {

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
      var ws =ss.getSheetByName("Options");
      var list =ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A2")
  .getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues()
      var htmlListArray = list.map(function(r) 
  {return '<option>' + r[0]  +   '</option>' ;  }).join('');  
      var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
      var ws1 =ss1.getSheetByName("Options2");
      var list1 =ws1.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A2")
    .getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues()
      var htmlListArray1 = list1.map(function(r)
  {return '<option>' + r[0]  +   '</option>' ;  }).join('');  

      return render("analyse",{list: htmlListArray, list1: htmlListArray1});

    }
```